# SVN Checkout by using Batchscript

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, batch-file

I am working on batchscripting which will checkout the folder by using svn and in some what i get success, and here is the code for this

```
@echo off
echo.
echo. [ SVN Updater ]

set SOURCE=C:\Documents and Settings\himanshu.jain\Desktop\checkout
set SVN=C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin
echo.
echo. Updating %SOURCE% to SVN...
"%SVN%\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:checkout /path:"%SOURCE%" /closeonend:2
echo. done.
echo.
echo. Operation complete.
```

But here I am getting a problem and i am trap in this that,i am able to give to the path on which the stuff will be checked out but don't know how  can I pass the SVN url in this batchscript......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the [TSVN Help](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html), when using `/command:checkout`:

> The `/path` specifies the target directory
>   and the `/url` specifies the URL to checkout from. If you specify the
>   key `/blockpathadjustments`, the automatic checkout path adjustments are
>   blocked. The `/revision:XXX` specifies the revision to check out.

So you're looking for `/url`.